# how make an array of items with one occurance from an array of items more than 2 occurrances in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

i have a vb.net program.
i have an array with items of 100 or more. in that array some items may be repetitive (ie occurance is more than once). i want to copy this array to another array with no repitition of items. For example

```
dim arr() as integer = { 2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 123, 144, 3, 6, 2, 176, 176, 10, 4, 4}
```

i want to copy this array to some other array and get like this

```
arr1()= {2,4,6,7,10,123,3,144,176}
```

is it possible. please help me

how to do it in vb.net

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it just a mistake that 144 is not part of the resulting array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method to achieve that :

```
Dim arr1 = arr.Distinct().ToArray()
```

**UPDATE :**

If `Distinct()` is not available in .NET framework version you're using (.NET fw before 3.5), this is one possible way to do the same manually :

```
Dim temp As New List(Of Integer)
For Each i As Integer In arr
    If Not temp.Contains(i) Then
        temp.Add(i)
    End If
Next
Dim arr1 = temp.ToArray()
```

Comment: ,thanks for quick reply. when i implement the same it is saying "distinct is not member of system.array".